# PHP: PDO foreach don't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I'm going to do a foreach loop to print the array values using this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = 1");
$query->execute();

foreach($query as $row) {
var_dump($row);
}
```

but the foreach cycle seems to be not executed, have nothing in my err.log

Can someone help?

Comment: You need to fetch the result

Comment: The return type of execute() can't possibly be void. I'm sure you need to foreach over whatever is returned by execute();

Comment: Example: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = 1");
$query->execute();

while($row = $query->fetch()){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Fetch() returns one row at a time, therefore you must do a while loop to fetch all results.

Or

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = 1");
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll();    

foreach($results as $row){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

In the above example, you use fetchAll() to get all rows at once. Then you use a foreach loop on those rows.

First you must prepare a query with the query() function. Then you must execute it with execute(), but then you must also retrieve the results, this isn't done automatically. To do that use fetch() or fetchAll()

Take a look at the following links:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: +1 for the cursor version (method 1). If you have 10000000 results, you probably don't want to fetchAll..

Comment: True depending on the use case the cursor version may be the better choice.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, great tip. Did not know it was useful for that case as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thats how to PDO:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = 1");
$stmt->execute();
$products = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($products as $product) {
var_dump($product);
}
```